# Size distribution of all known species in the domain bacteria

Tags: bacteriology, morphology

I have found the smallest bacteria are around 200nm (e.g Mycoplasma genitalium an ultramicrobacterium) and largest are around 700um (Thiomargarita namibiensis). I am looking for a graph that illustrate the size distribution of all bacteria species. I have googled with no luck.

Comment: You can find the average size of all characterized bacteria. That information is documented but perhaps nobody thought that a plotting a size distribution is useful (especially if you consider all bacteria and ignore the habitat and demographics).

Comment: You say you are looking for a graph. I assume size is the variable you require on one axis. What is the other?

Comment: @David in x-axis average size and in y-axis number of species

Comment: Sorry if I gave you false hope of an answer. I had forgotten you wanted physical size rather than genome size. You certainly will be out of luck for "all" bacterial species, because in recent years the number has increased vastly from genome sequencing of uncultured species (e.g. in the gut) which have not been characterized physically. You might like to take a look at the abstracts of [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-0965-1) recent Nature paper and [this one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1058-x) to get an idea of the scale of this.